# How to do automatically 'Text to columns' and 'save as' in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a source directory where I have .csv files (B1 cell). And a destination directory where I save same files as .xlsx (B2 cell), doing some processing like Text to Columns, choosing delimiter etc. with VBA macro shown below.

```
Sub FileList()

Dim directory As String, fileName As String, saveas As String, fileNameXlsx As String
Dim file As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook, LastRow As Long, LastRow1 As Long
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Set wb = Workbooks("CSV_File.xlsm")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Clear old data
LastRow = Sheets("FileList").Range("A" & Sheets("FileList").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("FileList").Select
Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Select
Selection.ClearContents

directory = wb.Sheets("Directory").Cells(1, 2).Value
saveas = wb.Sheets("Directory").Cells(2, 2).Value
file = Dir(directory & "*.csv")

While (file <> "")
i = i + 1
j = 1
wb.Sheets("FileList").Cells(i, j).Value = file
file = Dir
Wend

LastRow1 = Sheets("FileList").Range("A" & Sheets("FileList").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To LastRow1
On Error Resume Next
'.csv FileName
Range("B" & i).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-1],(LEN(RC[-1])-4))"
fileNameXlsx = wb.Sheets("FileList").Cells(i, 2).Value & ".xlsx"
fileName = wb.Sheets("FileList").Cells(i, 1).Value
'Open .xlsx file
Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Comma:=True, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
        Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1)), DecimalSeparator:= _
        ",", ThousandsSeparator:=" ", TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    ChDir saveas
    ActiveWorkbook.saveas fileNameXlsx _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
'Close .xlsx
Workbooks(fileNameXlsx).Close SaveChanges:=False
Next i

End Sub
```

It works quite well except the fact that each time a macro arrives to:

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Comma:=True, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
        Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1)), DecimalSeparator:= _
        ",", ThousandsSeparator:=" ", TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    ChDir saveas
```

It shows me a following message and I need to confirm it clicking “OK”. 
[image]

I would like to ask if there is any way to skip it (to click “OK”) automatically?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add

```
Applications.DisplayAlerts = False
```

at the top of your macro, so no alerts will be shown (at all!). Don't forget to set it back to true at the end of the code.